# Match URL with pdf and ignore .pdf

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace url (pdf to to/my/path/, say like example below.

https://www.example.com/en/pdf/myFileName.pdf

to

https://www.example.com/en/to/my/path/myFileName.pdf

I am using :

```
/pdf\/(.*)/
```

Replace with

```
/to/my/path/id/$1/
```

if my url is without .pdf than it works.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: According to your example you don't even need a regex. Just plain string replace `/pdf/` to `/anything you want/`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
pdf(?=\/)
```

Replace each match with:

```
to/my/path
```

**Explanation:**

- `pdf` - matches `pdf`
- `(?=\/)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position is followed by a `/`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GytlCE/1)**

Comment: Thank you..!
It gives me error : preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

I have edited my question, please check again.

Comment: @InvigorateSystems Does this [CODE](https://regex101.com/r/GytlCE/1/codegen?language=php) help?

Comment: yes a bit, I have edited my question, I am getting error, if you could review please?

Comment: Worked well, thank you so much.

Comment: @Gurman I like it. It's much simpler than what I came up with.